# How can I open, visualize and convert LandXML data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, import, xml, autocad-map, error-000732

I've received what I assumed was a DWG file but when I open it in AutoCAD Map 3D 2015 only data frames placeholders are shown. I was under the assumption that the person who sent the data forgot to include linked objects and drawings.

When I look as the files i received there is a single DWG file which i opened and long list of XML files.  I was told the project was created in Civil 3D and the XML files are some type of spatial 3D data.  Possibly LandXML?

I thought that a full features AutoCAD product such as Map 3D would be able to open any autodesk spatial data.

Ultimately I need to convert this data into an ESRI geodatabase feature class.

How can I open, visualize and convert LandXML in AutoCAD Map 3D 2015 or ArcGIS 10.3 (Standard, Spatial Analyst, 3D Analyst)

Note: I tried the **LandXML to TIN** tool but its giving me these errors:

> ERROR 000732: Input: Dataset
>   T:\GIS\DATABASES\Rainy_River_Project_Mine_Site_Features\Received
>   Data5-06-11 Water Management\Extracted\Clark Creek Dam.xml does not
>   exist or is not supported ERROR 000732: Output TIN Folder: Dataset
>   T:\GIS\DATABASES\Rainy_River_Project_Mine_Site_Features\Received
>   Data5-06-11 Water Management\Extracted\CONVERTED does not exist or is
>   not supported Failed to execute (LandXMLToTin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 3D Analyst Land XML to TIN tool did work when I run the toolbox tool itself rather than a command from the Python window.  Must have had the parameters wrong.

[image]